# SQL Query to merge different column data in to one

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to merge the values of three different columns name **ProcessFalseRedirect,ProcessTrueRedirect,GeneralRedirectToPP** into a single column named as **PPID**.

The query i'm using is this,

```
select ProcessFalseRedirect,ProcessTrueRedirect,GeneralRedirectToPP from IVR_PPMaster
```

which gives me the following result,

[image]

I want my output to be like this,

**PPID**
--------- 
PP-01
PP-02
PP-03
PP-04
PP-04a
PP-04b
PP-05

and so on.

I want a query which will ignore the blank rows and blank cells as well.

Please help.

Comment: have you tried joins ?outer join might do that for you.

Comment: @JibranKhan can you provide me the outer join query please. I haven't tried it. And is outer join possible on one table.

Comment: you are asking to keep data in ascending order instead of mergning

Comment: @SilentKiller Ya in ascending order, and also in a single column which will have distinct values of the above three columns combined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UNION` can help you.

```
select ProcessFalseRedirect PPID from IVR_PPMaster
union
select ProcessTrueRedirect from IVR_PPMaster
union
select GeneralRedirectToPP from IVR_PPMaster
```

To get data in ascending order use this:

```
select PPID from
(
  select ProcessFalseRedirect PPID from IVR_PPMaster
  union
  select ProcessTrueRedirect from IVR_PPMaster
  union
  select GeneralRedirectToPP from IVR_PPMaster
) p
order by PPID
```

Notice, that there are difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`.

Comment: This worked. It was giving the first row as null. So i added a where clause to it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
(SELECT ProcessFalseRedirect PPID FROM IVR_PPMaster WHERE ProcessFalseRedirect IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT ProcessTrueRedirect FROM IVR_PPMaster WHERE ProcessTrueRedirect IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT GeneralRedirectToPP FROM IVR_PPMaster WHERE GeneralRedirectToPP IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY ProcessFalseRedirect
```

Comment: this will give all the values whereas in case of `UNION` it will show only one value if their are multiple same values in a row

Answer (score 1):

Please do like this

```
SELECT ProcessFalseRedirect FROM IVR_PPMaster where ProcessFalseRedirect<>''
UNION
SELECT ProcessTrueRedirect from IVR_PPMaster where ProcessTrueRedirect<>'' 
UNION 
SELECT GeneralRedirectionTopp from IVR_PPMaster where GeneralRedirectionTopp<>''
```

Answer (score 1):

For Sql Server 2008+:

```
SELECT PPID
FROM IVR_PPMaster
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (ProcessFalseRedirect),
                    (ProcessTrueRedirect),
                    (GeneralRedirectToPP) ) AS Lines(PPID)
ORDER BY PPID
```

Solution explanation can be found here: [Table Value Constructors in SQL Server 2008](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/)